# Gimp – blend between layers controlled by a heightmap

Tags: gimp, layers

Suppose, I have a gray-scaled height map and ten layers with different diffuse textures or solid color textures.

I would like to blend these texture layers in a way determined by the heightmap, as follows: If a heightmap pixel is white, then pixel in the result will come from layer 10; if the heightmap pixel is black, from layer 1; if it’s between, it will show a layer between.

It’s like a terrain where on top there is a snow texture, and at the bottom, there is a water texture.

Comment: Do you want to mix the different layers as well? E.g., if your heightmap pixel is 5 % black, your final pixel will be half between the corresponding pixel from layer 10 and 9?

Comment: I've done something similar with [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). You can [load the images](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html) as matrix of pixels and perform conditional operations (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111860/selecting-only-a-specific-number-of-rows-fulfilling-a-condition) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132092/what-is-your-favourite-matlab-octave-programming-trick)). You can save the procedure for further use.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the height map channel to an alpha channel. For each channel layer

- Then use  threshold filter on each layer alpha so that the one with highest threshold is the back most layer.
- apply the alpha to your layer